# Virtualization limits for Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS with KVM

Tags: server, kernel, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, openstack

Essentially I'm after something like [this](https://access.redhat.com/articles/rhel-kvm-limits), but for Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS.

I'm trying to create some KVM guests with very large 1TB+ RAM (through OpenStack Nova). I can boot the 1TB VM fine, but I get a kernel panic with the 2TB flavor. Just wondering if I'm running into a kernel limit with the Ubuntu KVM implementation?

Comment: What kind of kernel panic do you get? In the host or in the guest? And I assume you are talking about the virtual hard drive sizes, right? I am not aware of hardware that support 2TB **RAM**. What kind of storage backend are you using with KVM? qcow2 files, LVM, physical disks, etc. And please include the exact kernel version you are using `uname -a` and an excerpt of the kernel traceback you probably see on your screen. Please [edit] your question to include all these details so we can help you better.

Comment: If you indeed mean RAM maximum sizes, then 1TB is the upper limit for older Linux kernels ([source](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116645)). So please share also what kind of guest OS you are using and kernel (also `uname -a` from within the guest OS).

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered here https://serverfault.com/questions/343756/kvm-maximum-number-of-cores-and-amount-of-memory-for-vms

Basically VM core is a process running is a host, so there is no limits. But if you think can you run a process with 2TB in a host with 1TB physical memory, its is possible if you have at least 1TB swap. But it must be very, very slow. So there is no mean to run in a host VM that has more memory than host has. And there is no mean to define more cores to VM than host has.